# Reticulate not setting python path

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am trying to use reticulate in R.

In bash I get:

```
which python
# ~/.pyenv/shims/python
```

But when I set it in R I never get it to work. Could someone help me understand why?

```
library(reticulate)
my_python='~/.pyenv/shims/python'
use_python(my_python, required = T)  # throws no message
py_config() #throws error below
#Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : 
# Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
```

Note that I made sure that `~/pyenv/shims/` is in `$PATH`.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance

Comment: There is a dot missing before pyenv?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it when writing the post. In my R code I had included it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem, after a lot of searching I stumbled upon this. Hopefully it will help: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/291#issuecomment-437143751

From another poster in the same thread:
"You need to use a version of Python built with the dynamically loadable
library (.dylib). R can't link to a static Python library."